# mysql hostname with path "localhost:/some/path/ms.sock"

Tags: path, mysql, hostname

Im connecting to mysql database with server defined as `localhost:/some/path/ms.sock`, can anyone explain how does this works? It surely is a path since `localhost:/some/../some/path/ms.sock` works as well, but when i run this `exec` from php

```
mysqldump -h localhost:/some/path/ms.sock -u xxx -pxxx xxx
```

it writes `Error: 2005: Unknown MySQL server host 'localhost:/some/path/ms.sock'` The PHP script is in the same directory. However this works fine:

```
new mysqli("localhost:/some/path/ms.sock", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/some/path/ms.sock` refers to the [Unix domain socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) through wich PHP will [connect to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket) (this is one of the three [connection protocols](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol) supported by MySQL, besides the usual TCP/IP).

This path must be provided to the `mysql*` clients with the [`--socket`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html#option_general_socket) (or `-S`) option:

```
mysqldump -h localhost -S /some/path/ms.sock -u ...
```